# My application works on all browsers except for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser, html-table

I have a slight problem here:

I have a function where it would add rows after a user has entered in a questioned inside a textarea and then submits the question, if question is valid then it will add a row in the table with the question inside the row.

This works in all the main browsers except for one (surprise, surprise it is Internet Explorer). In Internet explorer it does not add a row when I submit the question, after I click on the submit button it doesn't add a row. My validation of the question works but it doesn't add the row when the question is valid.

Why does my function not work in Internet Explorer?

Below is my code:

Javascript:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var cell,
        input,
        alertErrors = "",
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...
        qnum = 1;

    // Note, I'm using the .value instead of copying it
    // Also note the .length on the second check
    if (form.questionText.value == ""){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
    } else if (form.questionText.value.length < 5){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
    }

    // Stop execution with a return
    if (alertErrors != "") {
        alert(alertErrors);
        return;
    }

     cell = document.createElement("td"),
     input = document.createElement("textarea");
    cell.className = "question";
    input.name = "question_" + qnum;
    input.value = form.questionText.value;
    cell.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(cell);


     document.getElementById("qandatbl").appendChild(row);
     form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;

     ++qnum;
     document.getElementById("questionNum").innerHTML = qnum;
     form.questionText.value = "";
}
```

Html table and textarea and submit button for question:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >

//below is question textarea and submit button

<table id="middleDetails" border="1">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Question Number <span id="questionNum">1</span>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Question:</td> 
    <td>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        <input name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
    </th>
</tr>
</table>

<hr/>

//below is where the rows get added after question is submitted and valid

<table id="qandatbl" border="1">
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit questions to database" />
<input type="hidden" name="numberOfQuestions" value="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in IE?

Comment: IE and manipulating tables can be painful.  I remember having lots of hidden tables once as IE doesn't(didnt?) allow you to create a new table element in JS.

Comment: Which IE version? Is there a JavaScript error (yellow warning sign in status bar)? Is the document in Standards Mode?

Comment: *"My application works on all browsers except for Internet Explorer"* Gosh, that *never* happens. ;-)

Comment: @Russell: You can create new table elements via JavaScript in IE just fine, all the way back to IE6 in my experience (and I bet even IE5.5 could do it). You can't readily do it via `innerHTML` without pain, but you can do it just fine via `createElement` / `appendChild`. (Older versions don't handle colspan/rowspan very well, though, IIRC.)

Comment: Interesting @T.J.Crowder I believe it was IE6 which prevented us from doing it way back when.  We were copying "template" elements and updating values.  That was causing us grief!

Comment: @RoToRa there is no yellow warning sign in status bar, I am using the latest IE, (I am using a unversity computer) so I am guessing and it looks like the latest internet explorer

Comment: @danwellman I get no JS errors on the other browsers but how do I check in IE?

Comment: @Russell: Sounds like a lot of no fun. :-) This works in IE6: http://jsbin.com/afuluz But you were probably doing something more interesting than that...

Comment: @MalcolmPickup: Surely you can find the "About" box so you can see what version you're using? It'll be on the Help menu if you have menus, or off the one upper right-hand corner button if you don't. If you have IE8 or later, you have the Developer Tools, which will allow you to single-step through your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` JavaScript functions?

See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for advice on building tables dynamically